# Css code is not applied to page with bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I added my css file in html after bootstrap and my css is not aaplied to the page. What is the reason? I wan't to add hide-card class to the divs, but it is not working, even when I try to change simple background adding *!important* nothing happend.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dashboard.css">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="admin-dashboard.php" class="navbar-brand py-2">BOOKWARM</a>
        <form class="d-flex ms-auto mx-3">
          <!--search-->
          <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search books.." id="search-box" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-light" id="search" type="button"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
        </form>
        <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="bi bi-person-circle"></i>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <a class="btn btn-primary " data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#offcanvasExample" role="button" aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
  Link with href
</a>

<!-- card --->
<div class="offcanvas bg-dark sidebar-nav offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasExample" aria-labelledby="offcanvasExampleLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header ">
    <div class="user-display">
      <img src="./image/avatar.jpg" class="profile-picture" alt="">
      <h4 class="name"> Welcome, Joe</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
    <div>
      Some text as placeholder. In real life you can have the elements you have chosen. Like, text, images, lists, etc.
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown mt-3">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown button
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Daily Top -->
  <div class="top-today">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <h1>Top Books Today </h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="btn button left-btn ">
          <i class="bi bi-caret-left-square-fill"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="btn button right-btn">
          <i class="bi bi-caret-right-square-fill"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--first card-->
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
      <div class="card my-4" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title" id="">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!--scd card-->
        <div class="card my-4" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!--third card-->
        <div class="card my-4" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>


      <div class="results book-card" id="results">
      
      </div>

      
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    overflow: auto !important;
}
.sidebar-nav{
    width: 270px;
    transform:none;
    visibility: visible !important;
    top: 62px;
    height: calc(100%-62px);
    color: white !important;
}
.user-display{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.name{
    margin: 3px;
}
.profile-picture{
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.hide-cards{
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
.book-cover{
    align-items: center;
}
.book-card{
    margin-left: 280px;
}
.top-today{
    margin-left: 280px;
}
#text{
    font-size: 250px;
}

 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     body {
         overflow: auto !important;
     } 
     .offcanvas-backdrop::before{
         display: none;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Did you checked network tab if it's actually loaded? Maybe path to file is wrong and it's not accessible?

Comment: As @Justinas said, hit F12 and check the applied & computed styles..

Answer (score 0):

try to correct your path to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dashboard.css">`, or  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dashboard.css">`. Typically, your problem has to do with the file location path.

Comment: thank you, I tried the first one and it's working, but I didn't put "./" because css file are in the same folder, but surprisely it worked, thank you once again :)

Comment: I'm glad I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Here u didn't add `hide-cards` class to the bootstrap cards that's why the style are not applied to the cards.